# using JQueries $.GetScript to load an Angular controller into another script

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm having some issues when trying to write a JS framework. I want to basically define 1 JavaScript file in my HTML like this:

```
<script src="framework.JS"></script>
```

I intend to use $.getScript to include a number of JavaScripts into a single file:

However when I try to include an Angular controller it doesn't work.

```
$.getScript('controller.js', function() { ...
```

Instead I get the console error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module framework.ui due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'framework.ui' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FDcZM4PHOokRFza5eUaO?p=preview

In the index.html if you comment out the line:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

and uncomment the line above:

```
<!--  <script src="controller.js"></script> -->
```

it you will see it all works.

I'd really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: `$.getScript` does not combine files. Angular doesn't accept lazy loading controllers by default either

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's better never to mix JQuery with Angular.

The problem is that when the Angular bootstraps it wants that all modules are already included but JQuery loads that modules after Angular bootstraps.

Actually it is unnecessary to lazy-load modules in 99% cases. And it is non-trivial problem to implement it. In all common cases it's better to concatenate all Angular's modules before including it to your page. Look [this article](https://medium.com/@dickeyxxx/best-practices-for-building-angular-js-apps-266c1a4a6917) for more details.

I personally using following gulp task to perform the concatination:

```
gulp.task('concat', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'js/**/angular.js', // _allways_ include angular first
            'js/**/!(*mock*|angular.js|angular.min.js).js' // exclude mocks and angular to avoid oncluding it twice
        ])
        .pipe(sourcemap.init({loadMaps: true})) // I use sourcemaps to see my _files_ in debugger, not only modules
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemap.write({
            includeContent: false,
            sourceRoot: '/home/myself/projects/myProject/js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['concat']);
});
```

Comment: While your suggestion may be true, I do not think it answers the question. I want to dynamically pass a directive-name and directive-url, fetch the JS, execute it and `$compile/append` it into my DOM. Is that not possible? (Sorry, I know this answer is old)

Comment: Wow. TBH, I don't even remember that I used AngularJS to the extend I've been able to write about it on SO. =) If you're talking about modern Angular (not AngularJS), I believe it supports "normal" dynamic imports, e.g. see here: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/dynamic-imports-the-best-way-to-improve-angular-application-performance-2295f25adf83. The guy in article imports a predefined string, but it may as well be a variable. If you're asking about AngularJS, sorry, I don't remember anything about it.